# Drill through is not defined in ssas cube while connecting with excel

Tags: ssas, cube

This issue is irritating me a lot. I have defined a drill through action in SSAs cube and added proper role and added members as well, earlier I was able to drill through using excel sheet. But suddenly it is showing me that no actions defined. I checked everything added members in admin role but again not able to drill through using excel. Anyone has faced the same issue?? Or m missing something.

I had added some measures in measure group afterwards.

Comment: Can you post your drillthrough definition from SSDT? Did you make it the default drillthrough action? Are you possibly connected to a perspective where the action doesn't exist?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. But I dint create any perspective. How to check drill through is default or not?

Comment: Any luck?  I am experiencing the same issue.